# Como embutir uma biblioteca dentro da outra?

Tags: c, c++, library

Eu criei uma biblioteca para desenvolvimento de jogos em C++. Só que a minha biblioteca precisa de uma outra para fazer a exibição das imagens na tela, o SDL2. Assim cada vez que alguém quiser usar a minha biblioteca, a pessoa teria que linkar a minha e o SDL2. Ex:

```
g++ -o main.exe main.cpp -lminha_lib -lSDL2
```

Então gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de contornar esta situação, ao invés de ter que linkar as duas a pessoa só precisaria de linkar a biblioteca que criei. Ex:

```
g++ -o main.exe main.cpp -lminha_lib
```

Comment: Windows mesmo? Que eu tenho a _impressão_ de que no Linux seria possível apenas adicionar o `.a` da outra biblioteca dentro da sua. Ou então até mesma desempacotar a biblioteca estática e reempacotar os demais arquivos objeto com os da sua biblioteca

Comment: Eu estou usando o Linux, mas gostaria de uma solução que resultasse para os dois sistemas. Já tentei adicionar o .a da outra biblioteca na minha mas não resultou, na hora de compilar o código cliente dá erro de linkedição. Eu também estive lendo sobre a segunda solução que você propôs, mas fiquei sabendo que é muito arriscado, porque se tiver dois símbolos iguais (funções ou variáveis) nos dois arquivos .a, uma deles é perdido no momento da reempacotação (mas ainda não testei a hipótese).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a SDL2 oferecer uma versão estática da biblioteca você pode compilar o seu projeto embutindo a SDL2 na sua biblioteca, assim o seu usuário final só precisa linkar contra a sua biblioteca.

Você pode ver essa discussão aqui: http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?p=39289

http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&sl=auto&tl=pt&u=http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?p=39289

> A ligação estática funciona, mas recomendo que você use HAVE_LIBC e o 
>   Biblioteca de tempo de execução Visual C ++ neste caso. As implementações SDL para 
>   As funções específicas do Visual C ++ podem causar problemas de outra forma.
>
> Se o anexo for concluído, ele contém um arquivo em lotes (gmail 
>   não me deixou enviar como um .bat. Basta renomeá-lo.) E dois arquivos C que 
>   pode ser semelhante à sua situação. Baixe a fonte SDL 2 e 
>   extrai-o ao lado desses arquivos. Eu também incluí o 
>   SDL_config_windows.h para MSVC 2010 se você criar com isso. Eu acho que o 
>   HAVE_X define para HAVE_LIBC são adaptados para 2012.
>
> Se você executar build.bat no ambiente de compilação, ele deve renderizar uma DLL 
>   com SDL 2 estáticamente ligado e um executável importando alguns 
>   funciona a partir dele. Eu tenho algumas opções específicas x86 para suprimir 
>   avisos, mas alterá-los para x64 para criar uma compilação de 64 bits. 
>   Trabalhe perfeitamente.
>
> Além disso, pode ser útil se pudermos ver como você se encaixa 
>   juntos. cl.exe e link.exe invocações e tudo isso.

E claro que isso tem implicações de licenciamento, mas parece que para a versão 2 isso foi modificado conforme apresentado aqui: https://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation#Static_linking

http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&sl=auto&tl=pt&u=https://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation#Static_linking

> Ligação estática
>   O SDL 2.0, ao contrário de 1.2, usa a licença zlib , o que significa que você pode criar uma biblioteca estática conectada diretamente ao seu programa ou simplesmente compilar o código C da SDL diretamente como parte de seu projeto. Você está completamente autorizado a fazer isso. No entanto, encorajamos você a não fazer isso por vários motivos técnicos e morais (consulte docs / README-dynapi.md ) e não abrangerá os detalhes de como neste documento. Você pode não vincular SDL 1.2 na maioria dos casos devido ao licenciamento da LGPL, mas você realmente deve parar de usar o SDL 1.2 de qualquer maneira.

Comment: Tem como colocar o conteúdo desses links para ficar visível para todos?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado coloquei as partes que achei que eram as mais importantes e inclui o link para tradução.

Answer (score 0):

Baixe a biblioteca SDL2 e incremente-a em seu código. Imagino que você já deva ter feito isso, o jeito mesmo seria o usuário ter que linkar nas duas para o código rodar. Se você já adicionar essa biblioteca dentro do arquivo de seu código o usuário terá apenas que fazer uma vez.

Comment: Não entendi o quizeste dizer com " adicionar essa biblioteca dentro do arquivo de seu código". Gostaria que me explicasses de forma mais detalhada.

Answer (score 0):

No código da sua biblioteca você inclui o código da SDL2. Seria uma biblioteca só na hora de requisitar. 
É uma gambiarra, mas pode dar certo.

Comment: Gambiarra grande. Ainda mais não sabendo o que se precisa para compilar a outra biblioteca (a pergunta foi para o caso geral, o exemplo apenas que usa a SDL2). Precisaria ter as dependências de compilação dela, o que definitivamente não é adequado quando se trabalha em alto nível